# CustomRenderer to dynamically change border color

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have an `Entry`, which I want to add a red border around when a button is pressed if the entry is empty. Therefore I need to be able to change the color dynamically. (standard validator)

xaml:

```
<local:BorderChange Placeholder="Example Entry" BorderColor="#ff4444"></local:BorderChange>
```

PCL Control:

```
namespace Project
{
    public class BorderChange : Entry
    {
        public string BorderColor
        {
            get; 
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

iOS Customrenderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(BorderChange), typeof(BorderColorChange))]
namespace Project.iOS
{
    public class BorderColorChange : EntryRenderer
    {
    //init color

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(Control != null)
            {
                Control.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Blue; //This is where i want to add my color
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- How do I pass my property to the CustomRenderer, so that I can change the `BorderColor` parameter dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach for such needs is to use [Effects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/introduction).

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/passing-parameters/attached-properties) is a well-described example of how to create an effect with parameters as attached properties. You'll be able to bind a property from your view model (Let's say `IsValid` directly to the attached property of the effect).